# Forget WiFi ESP32

Tags: esp32, wifi

How can you make ESP32 forget all the Wi-Fi networks it was connected to? Or at least forget the one to which the board is currently connected?

Comment: `WiFi.disconnect()`

Comment: It only disables Wi-Fi, but when the ESP32 is turned on, it connects again automatically

Comment: connect to another network

Comment: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/wifi.html#disconnect

Comment: or erase the flash memory

Comment: Thank you! Use `WiFi.disconnect(false, true)`